# orthogonal projection of a vector in $R^2$ vs $R^3$ statement true/false

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently studying for a re-exam in linear algebra, and can't quite understand one question that is only a true/false answer.

a) Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be orthogonal projection on the line $l:t(0,1), t \in \mathbb{R}$, let $g:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be orthogonal projection on the line $l:t(1,1,1), t \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $A_f$ $A_g$ vara corresponding imaging matrix. Then the dimension of null space of $A_f$ is equal to the dimension of null space of $A_g$.

Can anyone give me a hint of how to think about this problem?

So far I just concluded that the imaging matrix of a orthogonal projection does not have full rank, since you can project multiple vectors on the to $l$ and receive the same result, which implies that the imaging matrix does have some dimension of null space that is not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the question is what space gets sent to 0 (that is the null space). If you look at the two dimensional case you get a line that is sent to 0 (the one orthogonal to your line through 0), and in 3 dimensions you get a plane (again the one orthogonal to your line just in 3 dimensions). Now a line is 1-dim and a plane 2-dim. So it is false.

Comment: I don't really understand. Why would I get a line that is sent to 0 in the first case, and why would I get a plane in the second case? I have a line I both cases, right?

Comment: yes, but in the first case the space orthogonal to your line at 0 is a line, and in the second a plane

Comment: Ooh, right, I understand! Thanks